# count consecutive statuses from each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, partition

I am trying to find a list of clients that have at least 3 consecutive items that are "processed". The following is what my table looks like:

### ClientID  ItemID   Status

1   1  Pending

1   2  Processed

1   3  Processed

2   4  Processed

2   5  Processed

1   6  Processed

1   7  Pending

2   8  Pending

2   9 Processed

3   10 Pending

3   11 Pending

2   12 Processed

3   13  Pending

2   14 Processed

1   15 Processed

2   16 Processed

Expected results:

1 (since it had 3 consecutive processed records from 2, 3, 6 )

2 (since it had 4 consecutive processed records from 9, 12,  14, 16)

As you can see, I define "consecutive" as the next record with the same ClientID and not as the next record in the table, this is what I am having trouble with. My counter restarts when the next clientid in the table is different.

my attempt:

```
WITH count
AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, count) NotPending
    FROM (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT COUNT(ItemId)
            FROM ##temp a
            WHERE status like '%pend%'
              AND ItemId < b.ItemId) AS count
        FROM  ##temp b
        WHERE status not like '%pend%'

    ) t1

)
SELECT distinct clientid from count where NotPending >= 3
```

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server.  Please tag SQL Server on your question.  You don't want people to give you solution for different dbms.  It's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Btw, to fix your current query you only need to add `AND ClientId = b.ClientId` to the `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number() to place rows with the same consecutive status in the same group:

```
select *,
  row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by ItemId) 
  - row_number() over (partition by ClientId, ItemStatus order by ItemId) as groupName
from Table1
order by ClientId, ItemId
```

Then you can count the number of entries per group:

```
select distinct ClientId, count(*) from (
    select *,
      row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by ItemId) 
      - row_number() over (partition by ClientId, ItemStatus order by ItemId) as groupName
    from Table1
) t 
where ItemStatus = 'Processed'
group by ClientId, groupName
having count(*) >= 3
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03c5b/24)

Answer (score 0):

In your example there are no clients with more than 5 consecutive items (and in your Select you check for >= 10).

Looking for 3 items, returns 1 & 2 for your example data:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT ClientID, ItemID, Status,
      -- returns 3 when there's only 'Processed'
      Sum(CASE WHEN Status = 'Processed' THEN 1 end) 
      Over (PARTITION BY ClientID
            ORDER BY ItemId
             -- 3 rows including current row
            ROWS 2 Preceding) AS Cnt
   FROM ##temp
 )
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID
FROM cte
WHERE Cnt = 3
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I edited my question, I want to look for clients with at least 3 consecutive items